# Wireless won't stay connected. Macbook Broadcom 4321 wireless card. Lubuntu 19.10

Tags: wireless, broadcom

Fresh install of Lubuntu 19.10 on early 2008 MacBook. Brand new to linux. Finally found/installed the correct wireless driver - used chili55's extensive post on which driver to install based on pci id. Now I have wireless, but it doesn't stay connected. Please help.

edit : $ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:0088]
        Kernel driver in use: wl
        Kernel modules: ssb, wl
```

$ nmcli device wifi list

```
IN-USE  SSID                 MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY 
        ICE VAN #55          Infra  3     195 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA2     
        Antici               Infra  157   195 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2
        LAN SOLO             Infra  36    195 Mbit/s  95      ▂▄▆█  WPA2     
        Johns                Infra  7     130 Mbit/s  32      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2
        MySpectrumWiFi42-2G  Infra  6     195 Mbit/s  30      ▂___  WPA2     
        Evets1               Infra  4     195 Mbit/s  29      ▂___  WPA2     
        TP-LINK_AP_0156      Infra  3     405 Mbit/s  27      ▂___  WPA2     
        Gordon Network       Infra  9     405 Mbit/s  25      ▂___  WPA2     
        MySpectrumWiFiCD-2G  Infra  5     260 Mbit/s  22      ▂___  WPA2     
        --                   Infra  9     130 Mbit/s  22      ▂___  WPA2     
        MySpectrumWiFi10-2G  Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  22      ▂___  WPA2     
        ATT3N8z959           Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  20      ▂___  WPA2     
        WIFIF4C3B3           Infra  1     195 Mbit/s  19      ▂___  WPA2     
        mycci12              Infra  1     195 Mbit/s  17      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2
        Broncos              Infra  10    130 Mbit/s  17      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2
        Amped_AP300          Infra  1     270 Mbit/s  15      ▂___  WPA1     
lines 1-17/17 (END)...skipping...
IN-USE  SSID                 MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
        ICE VAN #55          Infra  3     195 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA2             
        Antici               Infra  157   195 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2        
        LAN SOLO             Infra  36    195 Mbit/s  95      ▂▄▆█  WPA2             
        Johns                Infra  7     130 Mbit/s  32      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        MySpectrumWiFi42-2G  Infra  6     195 Mbit/s  30      ▂___  WPA2      
        Evets1               Infra  4     195 Mbit/s  29      ▂___  WPA2      
        TP-LINK_AP_0156      Infra  3     405 Mbit/s  27      ▂___  WPA2      
        Gordon Network       Infra  9     405 Mbit/s  25      ▂___  WPA2      
        MySpectrumWiFiCD-2G  Infra  5     260 Mbit/s  22      ▂___  WPA2      
        --                   Infra  9     130 Mbit/s  22      ▂___  WPA2      
        MySpectrumWiFi10-2G  Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  22      ▂___  WPA2      
        ATT3N8z959           Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  20      ▂___  WPA2      
        WIFIF4C3B3           Infra  1     195 Mbit/s  19      ▂___  WPA2      
        mycci12              Infra  1     195 Mbit/s  17      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
        Broncos              Infra  10    130 Mbit/s  17      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
        Amped_AP300          Infra  1     270 Mbit/s  15      ▂___  WPA1
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `nmcli device wifi list` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Here are several steps that I recommend. First, disable power saving in Network Manager; from the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
```

Next, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Then set your regulatory domain explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:
Code:
    sudo nano /etc/default/crda

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and close (Ctrl+x) the text editor.