# WiFi keeps disconnecting and sometimes WiFi speed is low and sometimes high in Ubuntu 18.04.4

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, internet

I am using Ubuntu Bionic 18.04.4 and I have Alfa AWUS036NHA WiFi adapter.

But my WiFi keeps on disconnecting and I need to reconnect and sometimes the speed of the WiFi varies from low to high, while in my Windows OS it works perfectly.

How can I fix this?

```
$ifconfig

ens32: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:e0:4c:36:05:79  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1103  bytes 116654 (116.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1103  bytes 116654 (116.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx00c0ca986fd0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.52  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::f4f:e959:d424:bed2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:c0:ca:98:6f:d0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 43274  bytes 60305894 (60.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 27542  bytes 2768703 (2.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

lusb

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 214b:7250  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 275d:0ba6  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Have you tried the usual troubleshooting steps here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220272/wireless-wont-stay-connected-macbook-broadcom-4321-wireless-card-lubuntu-19-1/1220731#1220731 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: i dont think that this will work as i am using an external wifi adapter which is atheros alfa NHA adaptor....so i am looking for a better answer

Comment: If it is a USB adapter, post output of `lsusb` to your question.

Comment: My suggestions have nothing to do with the type of adapter you have. Please check again.